# SAS Bar chart with percentages

Tags: sas, bar-chart

I am a new user to SAS so any feedback is greatly appreciated. I am trying to create a bar chart in SAS which shows the percent of patients that received a test by category (a stratification of risk) and then within that, show where the test was received (location). My dataset looks like this:

```
Category            Test        Test_location
High Risk           1           Site 1
Intermediate Risk   1           Site 2
Low Risk            0           .
Intermediate Risk   0           .
High Risk           1           Site 3
```

Where each patient is listed with the category they have been assigned to (variable 'Category'), an indicator variable that shows whether or not they received a test (variable 'test' where '1'=received test and '0'=did not receive test) and if they received a test, where that test took place (variable 'test_location').

I want to create a bar graph with the categories on the x axis and the yaxis showing the percentage of patients who got a test (test=1), and each bar showing how many tests occurred in Site 1, 2 and 3.

I have this code but it gives me the counts of patients who received test rather than percentages:

```
proc sgplot data=test;
vbar category / response=test
group=test_location groupdisplay=stack;
yaxis grid values=(0 to 100 by 10) label="Percentage of patients who received testing (%)";
label Category= "Risk Stratification"; 
keylegend /title="Testing Location" position=bottom;
quit;
```

I don't think proc sgplot has a percent stat, so I tried doing a proc freq but I can't figure out how to do that accurately for all of the variables I have.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT;

I added in percent stat like the poster below suggested, but it is not giving me the percentages I want (it gives me a pct_col output of test*category, and I want pct_row).
The below code gives me the percentages I want, but I also want to add test_location to show on each bar what percentages of patients were in each location.

```
proc tabulate data=test_util out=freq1;
class category test;
tables category,test*rowpctn;
run;
proc sgplot data=Freq1;
    where test=1;
    vbar category / response=pctn_10;
quit;
```

Example of what I want: 
In the dummy dataset below, for high risk patients, for example, I want a bar that shows 75% (12 patients with tests out of the total 16 high risk patients) received tests, and then have the bar shaded to show 41.66% of those test were at Site 1, 33.34% at Site 2 and 25% at Site 3. And so on for the intermediate and low risk categories. If there is a way to label the subsections with the exact percentages, that would be great too.

Dummy data set:

```
data test;
infile datalines missover;
   input ID Category $ Test Test_location $;
   datalines;
1 High 1 Site_1
2 High 1 Site_1
3 High 1 Site_1
4 High 1 Site_1
5 High 1 Site_1
6 High 1 Site_2
7 High 1 Site_2
8 High 1 Site_2
9 High 1 Site_2
10 High 1 Site_3
11 High 1 Site_3
12 High 1 Site_3
13 High 0
14 High 0
15 High 0
16 High 0
17 Intermediate 1 Site_1
18 Intermediate 1 Site_1
19 Intermediate 1 Site_2
20 Intermediate 0
21 Intermediate 0
22 Intermediate 0
23 Intermediate 0
24 Intermediate 0
25 Intermediate 0
26 Low 1 Site_1
27 Low 1 Site_1
28 Low 1 Site_1
29 Low 1 Site_2
30 Low 1 Site_2
31 Low 1 Site_2
32 Low 1 Site_3
33 Low 0
34 Low 0
35 Low 0
36 Low 0
37 Low 0
38 Low 0
;
```

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your edit.  Your `proc sql` there is unnecessary - you can add the `where` in a lot of different places, any of the out= or data= statements or in the proc itself.

Answer (score 0):

`proc sgplot` does have a percent stat, if you're in SAS 9.4+.  That wasn't added until that point (According to the doc, anyway; you might try it and see in case it's undocumented.)

If not, then `proc freq` should allow you to create values that `proc sgplot` with `vbarparm` can use.  You don't post your `proc freq` above so I don't know what you've tried yet, but look around; for example, [my MWSUG paper](http://www.mwsug.org/proceedings/2014/DV/MWSUG-2014-DV04.pdf) shows an example of doing this (for a different reason, but the result is largely the same).

Here's a `tabulate` that does the work - probably easier than using `freq`.

```
proc tabulate data=have out=freq1;
class category test test_location/missing;
tables test_location,category,test*pctn;
run;


proc sgplot data=Freq1;
    where test=1;
    vbar category / response=pctn_000 group=test_location;
quit;
```

Comment: thank you. but do you know of a way I could add my other variable 'test_location' to that to show where each test took place? I would like a stacked bar for each category that is colored to show how many tests took place in each site (ie: site 1, site 2, site 3). Thanks!

Comment: You just need to add it to your tabulate, and change the pctn_### variable (each # means one 'cross' type - in this case it's always 000).

Comment: The statistic I want for the bars is actually test*rowpctn (see my edit above). But then if I add in test_location to proc tabulate as you suggested, I'm not getting the right row percents anymore. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: You may need to add it in a different place.  Can you give an example with actual numbers that represent what you want?  Maybe make up a dataset that is dummied up with the actual values?

Comment: See my above edit for an example of what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sgplot data=mydata pctlevel=graph;
vbar Category / response=Test stat=percent
group=Test_location;
run;
```

Comment: As I noted in my answer - this is available but only in 9.4.

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of how your code works.